# Ruby date format difference between %-d vs %e or "no-padded" vs "blank-padded"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#strftime-method), there are two very similar values for formatting a date(time) string

1. `%-d` described as `no-padded (1..31)`
2. `%e` described as `blank-padded ( 1..31)`

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Look closely: the `1` for `%e` has a leading space.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between these two is the following:

`%-d` will print out the number without leading zero nor space ex:

```
DateTime.new(2016, 02, 01, 16, 00).strftime('%m/%-d/%Y')
> "02/1/2016"
```

`%e` will print out a leading space but not a leading zero

```
DateTime.new(2016, 02, 01, 16, 00).strftime('%m/%e/%Y')
> "02/ 1/2016"
```